# SideMenu left not using the full height of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, side-menu

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) to create a side menu in iOS, using Swift 4.

But, this only works for smaller screens like the iPhone SE or 5S. On bigger screens like the iPhone 6, this does not work as the side menu does not extend all the way down to the bottom of the screen:

[image: screenshot of side menu that doesn't go all the way down]

My code to create my side menu in `MainViewController`:

```
let menuLeftNavigationController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftMenuNavigationController") as! UISideMenuNavigationController
SideMenuManager.default.menuWidth = 260 
SideMenuManager.default.menuLeftNavigationController = menuLeftNavigationController
SideMenuManager.default.menuFadeStatusBar = false
SideMenuManager.default.menuPresentMode = .menuSlideIn
SideMenuManager.default.menuAnimationFadeStrength = 0.5
SideMenuManager.default.menuShadowOpacity = 0.8

// open with present
self.present(SideMenuManager.default.menuLeftNavigationController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

ViewController with SideMenu:

[image: storyboard screenshot]

Comment: Are you using autolayout constraints in the storyboard?

Comment: When I set constraint the height set correctely but the contentes inside view turns wrongs.

Comment: What do you mean? You have to make sure to add correct constraints to all the components of the view (such as your label, that image, etc).

Comment: I did positioned all components and set all constraints. I'll try to do it all over again.

Comment: You could post screenshots of your constraints and what the problem with the "contents inside turned wrong" looks like.

Comment: seems like you are providing static height to SideMenu,

Answer (score 0):

Tried to set leading, top, bottom and width constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i faced such problems every time i used storyboards or xibs to make UI for different screen sizes.
You can try to create this menu controller programmatically and then problem should go away.